# TinyMCE Issues in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, javascript, tinymce

I'm having some issues with TinyMCE, which is causing the editor not to work on CMS pages and causes products not to load when attempting to edit them.

When these issues are happening, I see this in the console: `[url]/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/tinymce.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404`

and `require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: tinymce`

Note: if I look into /static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US folder, I can confirm that tinymce.js is not there, but there's a en_US/tiny_mce_4 folder with tinymce.min.js in it.

Anyone know what's going on?

Edit: one infuriating thing is that, for some reason, everything is working on my development environment. I rsynced the public_html folder from dev to prod, dumped/imported its database, and still the issue persists. So weird!

Comment: Have you got anything or not?

Comment: May be this will help you: https://github.com/pavelleonidov/magento2-tinymce4

Comment: I have that @DhadukMitesh but thanks!

Comment: Hi @brackfost have u found solution for this?  I have been facing same issue after upgrade from m2. 2.3 ce to 2.3.1 ce can u please advise?

Comment: hi. I am facing same issue in mahento2.3.3 I cleared all the cache still getting same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, there was some additional cache clearing that needed to be performed. I had flushed redis and magento, but for anyone on MageMojo this is the command that fixed it:

`/usr/share/stratus/cli cache.all.clear`

Comment: how and where to run this commands ?

Comment: I am having the same error for Magento 2.3 so what should I do?. because it doesn't work after clearing cache

Comment: Need to execute this command from public_html?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what would work for your specific circumstances, but I'd look for non-Magento caches to clear (like redis above). I ran this from public_html yes @NagarajuKasa

Answer (score 1):

I have just updated my module https://github.com/pavelleonidov/magento2-tinymce4 which also fixes the issue in production context. Feel free to check it out. :)

Best regards,

Pavel

Comment: this is not working for me...

Answer (score 1):

Great man you save my day thank you , Pavel Leonidov