# Magento 2.3.1 CE Tinymce Error

Tags: magento2, product, javascript, cms, tinymce

We have upgraded Magento from 2.2.3 CE to 2.3.1 CE successfully. But we are facing few issues with the Tinymce js from admin end product edit page and cms pages etc.. when using Show/Hide Editor..

`Product Edit Page from admin end`.

[image: Product Edit Page]

`Admin end cms page:`

[image]

Please advise.

Comment: check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266578/tinymce-issues-in-magento-2-3

Comment: Yes i  tried but local instance also we are facing same issue